# Given two unsorted column ranges, How to get the match or lowerbound and match or higher entry?

Tags: excel

I have a type range and for each type a different amount range per type, the amount range is ascending but the total column is not. That is the difficulty for me.
As input I have a type and amount. The amount is not always an exact match. Therefor I would like the match as result if it is a match or the first lower and next entry of amount as a result.

I am trying with `match` and `index` : Do not mind the ; and , difference in the picture attached (my setting is different)

```
=INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(E2&VLOOKUP(E3,B2:B11,1),A2:A11&B2:B11,0))
=INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(E2&INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(E3,B2:B11,1)+1),A2:A11&B2:B11,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with array formulae.

If your inputs are in E2 and E3 and your data are in A1:B9 then

In E5 `=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$9<=E3,IF($A$2:$A$9=E2,$B$2:$B$9)))`

In E6 `=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$9>=E3,IF($A$2:$A$9=E2,$B$2:$B$9)))`

Both are array formula so confirm using Ctrl, Shift and Enter and curly brackets will appear round the formula.

[image]